# Mapbox sdk with androidx?

Tags: android, mapbox, androidx, mapbox-android

After adding all dependencies according to https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/ , when I tried to run application this error occurred :

Sync error :

> Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0 Affected Modules:
> app

Build Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not find legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0).
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-core-utils/1.0.0/legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.jar
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Here is my build.gradle module-level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hamimap.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.1'
}
```

Here is my build.gradle project-level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: 'my secret token'
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle configurations look ok at first glance. There could be an incompatibility between `api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'` and the Mapbox dependencies. Have you tried removing the dependency to see if this solves the problem?

Also, are you developing in Kotlin? If yes, you should add

```js
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

to your application level build.gradle.